# Vuetify - How to disable v-form input elements

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have been trying and investigating about disabling the form by default.

```
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
 <v-select v-model="test" :items="data" :disabled="status"></v- select>
 <v-text-field v-model="name" :disabled="status"></v-text-field>
</v-form>
```

I don't see any disable prop to the **v-form**. So i am just adding **disabled** prop to each and every input field to solve this problem. Like Angular adding **disable** prop to `<fieldset>` tag or to the **form** looks simple, is there any thing available in vuetify? any other approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this my self, made my own form that extends VForm and tried making a disabled directive for it (v-disabled="isDisabled").

Unfortunately at the moment without the knowledge and time to extend all of the components and buttons in question, what you are currently doing is the only way or else you get the mutating prop warning on setting `disabled` directly with an iterator and trying to set `isDisabled` will throw an "has no setter method error".

Vuetify needs to update the `input` and `button` components to allow pragmatic changes to the disabled property.

Having to set :disabled on each element isn't really that drastic but yes I agree that from the parent form it would be nice to have.

Comment: You are suggesting to add :disabled prop to each and every input element inside form?

Comment: Yes unfortunately.